# Is the Https connection trust, If Https cert public key is same? (HttpClient5)

Tags: java, https, x509certificate

In PKI system, You can use CA public key to verify a certificate:

```java
x509Certificate.verify(CAPublicKey);
```

But I want only trust the specified certificate rather than whole CA and all certs he sign. You can't verify an cert with itself public key And this won't work Then throw exception:

```java
x509Certificate.verify(currentCertificatePublicKey);
```

`java.security.SignatureException: Signature does not match`

So I try to do that:

```java
x509Certificate.getPublicKey().getEncoded().equals(currentCertificatePublicKey);
```

This working but I'm not sure is that safe. I did some research but I still can't 100% sure for it because none use https like that, So the question is:

Is there any possibility to cheat https client without certificate private key? (TLS_1.2)

Answer (score 0):

Using `.equals` on arrays is not correct to compare their contents.
This will check if both arrays are the same object.

The correct method to use is `Arrays.equals()`.

> Array.equals() :
> Two arrays are considered equal if both arrays contain the same number
> of elements, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two arrays
> are equal.
> [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(byte[],%20byte[])](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(byte%5B%5D,%20byte%5B%5D))

```
byte[] certificatePublicKey = x509Certificate.getPublicKey().getEncoded();
byte[] storedPublicKey = currentCertificatePublicKey.getEncoded();

bool isPublicKeyCorrect = Arrays.equal(certificatePublicKey, storedPublicKey);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. And is that safe in cert verify?